# Late 90's YA Alien Book

Tags: story-identification

Trying to find a book a read in the late 90's. Young Adult fiction story about aliens secretly coming to earth & the main characters trying to stop them. I recall it surrounding TV towers and power lines

Comment: Can you remember anything about the cover?  What is the country of origin?

Comment: And what exactly is surrounding these towers and power lines? The alien? Their ship? The cover art?

Answer (score 2):

This might be "You Remember Me" by Nicholas Fisk, or it's prequel "Grinny", or a 2-in-1 of both. My memory's a bit hazy, but I read them in the early or mid 90s.

"aliens secretly coming to earth & the main characters trying to stop them." - check. In both books, one alien had arrived in advance, disguised as a human, to start infiltrating society and preparing the humans for obedience. I don't remember if it was the same alien in both. The alien was sufficiently capable of hypnosis to have rendered most of the adults incapable of detecting or doing anything about them - only the children who were the protagonists could.

"surrounding TV towers and power lines" I do know the aliens were scared of electricity. In the first book, the children forced the alien to hold a (live) power cable - this was an unpleasant (traumatic?) enough experience for the alien to flee Earth as soon as they let it go. In the second book, the infiltrating alien had successfully created a mass media persona and was making a lot of TV appearances.